# How do I display ejs data on html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, server, ejs

I want users to fill out a form embedded a section of an HTML website, and have their submitted responses be updated every time on the same HTML file, rather than displaying their responses on a separate output.ejs file. I just don't know how beyond this point. What would I change in my server file?

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var formdata = [];

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }); 
   app.use(urlencodedParser);

   app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('index');
    })

   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

   app.post('/processform', function(req,res) {

    let data = new Object();
    data.street = req.body.street;
    data.pet = req.body.pet;


    formdata.push(data);

    let passedindata = new Object();
    passedindata.formdata = formdata;


  res.render("output.ejs", passedindata);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make another API endpoint that return `formdata`. After the user successfully post a response, instead of rendering output.ejs, have your form page make this API call to get the newly updated `formdata`, then process on the frontend as you please.